# PageMethods in .Net1.1

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, jquery

Can I use PageMethods in .net1.1?I have to call a server side method call from client side?

How to use

PageMethods.MyMethod();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such construct available in .NET 1.1. You can try servicing calls using XML Web Services or using your own HTTP handler, but it won't work the way it does with ASP.NET AJAX in 2.0 (unless you go through the effort to recreate it).

There was a tool called [AJAX Pro](http://ajaxpro.codeplex.com/) that will produce something kind of like page methods, however, I doubt it's maintained any longer.